# How to upload app to Play Store with android:exported issue

Tags: ionic-framework

Currently I am using API 30 in my app, and there is no problem found when I upload it to Play Store, the issue come when I hear news about Play Store will no longer accept target API 30 or lower soon, so I try to update API to 31, but when I upload to Play Store it say that my app need to provide `android:exported` property, so I add that property in AndroidManifest.xml to any `<intent-filter>` tag. Then I try to re-upload my app and still Play Store not accept due not provide 'android:exported' issue.

After search for solve the problem I found a solution that I believe is the main problem, it say probably caused by plugin issue, and here in my app I am using `onesignal` plugin, version 2.11.3, I try to re-install the plugin use latest version, which is 3.1.0, but the plugin is not running, and when I debug it, it say `plugin_not_installed`, but when I try to upload to Play Store it get success to upload.

This is some action that already taken this far :

- using `this.platform.ready()` before use plugin
- re-install platform (I am using android)
- re-install plugin (remove & add), no problem found when install
- delete `node_modules, platform, plugins, www` folder, `npm i`, then rebuild

If you have any solution for this please reply below. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could add something to your config.xml inside the android platform to set the exported attribute to true, e.g.

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application/activity[@android:name='<YourOneSignalActivity>']" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <activity android:exported="true" />
</edit-config>
```

where `<YourOneSignalActivity>` is the name of your OneSignal activity.

Cordova edit-config help is [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/plugin_ref/spec.html#edit-config).

Comment: I already add android:exported property through ```<edit-config>``` in my config.xml, and success reflect to AndroidManifest.xml when build the app, but it still get error when upload to Play Store

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and luckily just fixed it. My app is ionic v1 based and uses onesignal-cordova-plugin v2.11.4.

1. Add the code below in your config.xml

   ```
    <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application/activity">
        <activity android:exported="true" />
    </edit-config>
   ```
2. Add the code below in your ./platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifext.xml

   ```
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.xxx.yyy" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.onesignal.BootUpReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.onesignal.UpgradeReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity android:exported="true" android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpenedActivityHMS" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   ```

Comment: Finally I've been solved this issue, it's come from the OneSignal module itself, previously I use the module from inside `@ionic-native`, and also try with `@awesome-cordova-plugins` but neither both is work. Until I try to load the module directly and follow documentation from OneSignal directly [link](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/cordova-sdk-setup) instead from Ionic documentation, and it's have different method to work with. Then it's already running seamlessly without any issue when the app build or upload to Play Store. Oh ya, currently I'm using Ionic v6 and OneSignal v3.2.0